# Is there a pull-down class for navbar in Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

There are **pull-right** and **pull-left** classes to align block elements. I'm wondering if there is corresponding **pull-top** and **pull-bottom** workable for navbar?

```
<header id="navbar" role="banner" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <a class="logo pull-left" href="/" title="Home">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="Home">
      </a>

      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <nav role="navigation">
          <ul class="menu nav">
            <li>...</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

To goal is to align the menu (`ul.nav`) to the bottom of navbar.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer to this really lies in the capabilities of CSS. `.pull-right` and `.pull-left` both apply a micro-clearfix and then float the element left or right in Twitter Bootstrap.

Creating `.pull-top` and `.pull-bottom` class' would not be feasible as the parent elements would need to have a `position:relative` applied, the element would then need man-handled around with `top` and `bottom` properties to have it placed properly. The alternatives would require the element to have a fixed height with negative margin applied to the top, of half the height and `top:50%` applied. Again this would need the parent to be `position:relative`.

As with any CSS framework, there are just some things you will have to do yourself :-(.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. Then, I should google some manual CSS way to do `pull-down` right? If I can make the parent element `position:relative`, what possible solutions I can use to create my own `pull-down`?

Comment: well in your example, give the container and the ul a position:relative. You would then need to play around with `bottom` and `top` properties. creating a pull-down class is not going to be possible. The values of top and bottom will change in each case.